# Correct way to use MagicalRecord in a concurrent NSOperation (MagicalRecord-2.3)

Tags: magicalrecord

With MR_contextForCurrentThread not being safe for Operations (and being deprecated), Im trying to ensure I understand the best pattern for series of read/writes in a concurrent operations.

It's been advised to use saveWithBlock for storing new records, and presumably deletion, which provides a context for use. The Count and fetch methods can be given a context, but still use MR_contextForCurrentThread by default.

Is the safest pattern to obtain a context using [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context] at the start of the operation, and use it for all actions. The operation depends on some async work, but not long running. Then perform a MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion when the operation is finished?

Answer (score 2):

What's the reason for using an NSOperation? There are two options here:

Use MagicalRecord's background saving blocks:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // Do your task for the background thread here
}];
```

The other option is (as you've already tried) to bundle it up into an NSOperation. Yes, I would cache an instance of a private queue context using `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_newContext]` (sorry, I deprecated the `MR_context` method this afternoon in favour of a clearer alternative). Be aware that unless you manually merge changes from other contexts, the private queue context that you create will be a snapshot of the parent context at the point in time that you created it. Generally that's not a problem for short running background tasks.

Managed Object Contexts are really lightweight and cheap to create — whenever you're about to do work on any thread other than the main thread, just initialise and use a new context. It keeps things simple. Personally, I favour the `+ saveWithBlock:` and associated methods — they're just simple.

Hope that helps!

Comment: can you do multiple saveWithBlocks at the same time (ie in different threads) ?

Comment: I believe so, yes. My understanding is that the root saving context will lock while changes are saved from each child context within the `saveWithBlock:` method call (on a background thread), as will the persistent store coordinator while it's writing to disk.

Comment: I used the second option where I created an instance of NSManagedObjectContext for each operation I have and I turned on the concurrency debugging flag in Xcode. it stops the app the first time I try to createEntity using the local context so it seems there is something missing.. here is the question I already posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206967/multithreading-violation-core-data

Comment: @TonyArnold I'm using `saveWithBlocks` in different thread , each with its `localContext` as advised, but randomly I'm getting a data duplicates, ex. I get 2 or 3 ones of the same records... I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `saveWithBlock` from multiple threads (concurrent `NSOperations`) if you want to:

- rely on create by primary attribute feature of Magical Record
- rely on automatic establishment of relationships (which relies on primary attribute)
- manually fetch/MR_find objects and do save based on result of it

This is because whenever you use `saveWithBlock` new local context created, so that multiple context created in the same time and they don't know about changes in each other. As Tony mentioned `localContext` is a snapshot of `rootContext` and changes goes only in one direction, from `localContext` to `rootContext`, but not vice versa.

Here is thread-save (or even consistency-safe in terms of MagicalRecord) method that synchronizes calls to `saveWithBlock`:

```
@implementation MagicalRecord (MyActions)
+ (void) my_saveWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block completion:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completion;
{
    static dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    });
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:block
            completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                if (completion){
                    completion(success, error);
                }
            }];
    });
}
@end
```