# Multithreading violation core data

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an app where I download the data on startup using a list of operations and it crashes randomly for unknown core data reasons so I spent few days on checking the best practices to update/fetch data in multithreading core data with MagicalRecord. One of the options was to enable the multithreading debugger `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` where Xcode stops the apps when it violates one of their rules. So, Xcode stops my app on this line `[SyncRequestEntity MR_createEntityInContext:[self getPrivateContext]]`

```
+ (MagicalRecordVersionNumber) version
{
    return MagicalRecordVersionNumber2_3;
}
@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (MagicalRecord) 

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_context
{
    return [self MR_contextWithParent:[self MR_rootSavingContext]];
}

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_contextWithParent:(NSManagedObjectContext *)parentContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self MR_newPrivateQueueContext];
    [context setParentContext:parentContext];
    [context MR_obtainPermanentIDsBeforeSaving];
    return context;
}

- (void) MR_obtainPermanentIDsBeforeSaving
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(MR_contextWillSave:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification
                                                   object:self];
}
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_newPrivateQueueContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    MRLogInfo(@"Created new private queue context: %@", context);
    return context;
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

    - (NSManagedObjectContext *) getPrivateContext
    {
        if (self.privateContext == nil)
        {
            self.privateContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
        }
        return self.privateContext;
    }

    - (SyncRequestEntity *) getSyncRequest
    {
        SyncRequestEntity *syncRequest = [SyncRequestEntity MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"key" withValue:self.itemKey inContext:[self getPrivateContext]];

        // Checking if the entity was sync previously with the same filters.
        if (syncRequest == nil)
        {
            syncRequest = [SyncRequestEntity MR_createEntityInContext:    [self getPrivateContext]];
        }

        return syncRequest;
    }
@end

@implementation NSManagedObject (MagicalRecord)
+ (id) MR_createEntityInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(insertInManagedObjectContext:)] && context != nil)
    {
        id entity = [self performSelector:@selector(insertInManagedObjectContext:) withObject:context];
        return entity;
    }
    else
    {
        NSEntityDescription *entity = nil;
        if (context == nil)
        {
            entity = [self MR_entityDescription];
        }
        else
        {
            entity  = [self MR_entityDescriptionInContext:context];
        }

        if (entity == nil)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        return [[self alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    }
}
@end
```

The `privateContext` is a local variable for each operation so I have private contexts for each operation in order to not interrupt the main one. The point is that I create one private context for each thread and I'm just trying to create a new `NSManagedObject` instance using this context and Xcode says that I'm violating the multithreading core data rules. Does anyone have any clue on what's happening?

Comment: What is the code of `MR_context`? Did you take in account that blocks can run on different threads?

Comment: Adding details @AminNegm-Awad. I'm not using any block here.

Comment: Which version of MagicalRecord are you using?

Comment: @casademora, it's 2.3 as you can see in the updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue when developing our own app.

When you try to perform a write operation in a thread different to the context one, it crash sometimes.

Our solution was to make a private manager on the `AppDelegate.m` file. Just add this code:

```objc
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getPrivateManagedObjectContext
{
    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return self.managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self getPersistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Then when you need to perform any operation, you should use this method that ensures the block is running on the same thread of the context:

```objc
[self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{...}];
[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{...}];
```

Comment: Why do I need to use performBlock? I'm already on a background thread (NSOperation) I just want to create/fetch/insert entities using the privateContext I create for each operation but it seems I'm violating one of their rules which I don't understand so far.

Comment: The problem is that if you perform simultaneous write operations it may crash. You need to use just one private context and perform each operation in the same context thread.

Comment: What is the difference between having one global private context and having private context for each thread? it seems to me I will get the same result, right?

Comment: The main problem is that all operation should be in the performBlock or performBlockAndWait. Having only one, will ensure you that all the threads will use the same "threads queue".

Comment: I tried to have just one private context for all the threads and I got the same result..